# Multiple EntityManagers in EventSubscriber

Tags: symfony4

I can call default entity manager from EventSubscriber but now i want to check some value in second database.

My codde:

```
class AuthenticationSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    public $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event)
    {}


    public function onKernelResponse(ResponseEvent $event)
    {}

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => ['onKernelRequest', 40],
            KernelEvents::RESPONSE => 'onKernelResponse',
        ];
    }
}
```

What is necessary to do to call second database in my case?

Answer (score 0):

solution is:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class AuthenticationSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    public $em;

    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    public $em2;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->em = $container->get('doctrine')->getManager('default');
        $this->em2 = $container->get('doctrine')->getManager('em2');
    }

    (...)
}
```